# Fill NSStackView with NSArray and NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsstackview

I have a Stack to fill with an array of views.

```
_countViewArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
_countViewArray = @[self.a.view,self.b.view,self.c.view];
_stackView = [NSStackView stackViewWithViews:_countViewArray];
```

It's work well.
If I want replace this array with a mutable array how can do it?

I tried this code for a "dynamic" stack view and finally convert mutable array in simple array but doesn't work:

```
_mutableCountViewArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[_mutableCountViewArray addObject:@[self.a.view]];
if (caseCondition){
   [_mutableCountViewArray addObject:@[self.b.view]];
}
[_mutableCountViewArray addObject:@[self.c.view]];

_countViewArray = [_mutableCountViewArray copy];
_stackView = [NSStackView stackViewWithViews:_countViewArray];
```

in consolle if I print mutable array I have:

```
(
    (
    "<NSView: 0x600000121ea0>"
),
    (
    "<NSView: 0x600000120780>"
,
    (
    "<NSView: 0x6000001235a0>"
)
)
```

How can I solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding arrays (containing a single view) instead of views...

Remember, `@[x]` is a literal expression defining an `NSArray` containing `x`

---

So a line like this:

```
[_mutableCountViewArray addObject:@[self.a.view]];
```

should become:

```
[_mutableCountViewArray addObject:self.a.view];
```

(of course, this applies to every object you add in the next few lines...)

---

Also, as a sidenote:

```
_countViewArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
```

in your first snippet is redundant since you reassign a value in the next line...

Comment: Hey, thanks! I do not understand the sense of redundant. The first block of code is without mutable array, the second alloc of array is understood...

Comment: @alfioal I mean that you can safely delete the line `_countViewArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];` (in the case you use the first snippet) since you assign a different value to `_countViewArray` again in the next line... I hope that this makes sense :)

Comment: Ah, ok! I understand!